# Can you suggest a approach for this system design question?

Tags: algorithm, system

was asked a design question for software engineer position. I couldn't get anywhere near the question, can you guys suggest a good solution for this question?

Question:
There are 10 Servers which has 5 parameters such as A,B,C,D,E. Each parameter is time stamped and written to a logfile. As a note all 10 devices write to a single log file. The format of the log will be device id, time stamp, parameter(A or B or C or D or E)
eg

```
  device 1, 5 june , A=4
  device 5 ,6 june , C =3
  device 4 ,5 june , A =3
```

Design a logging mechanism where the user would query your API with device id and parameter he wants (A or B or C or D or E) with increasing timestamp and the single log file.

I just wrote a function which would traverse the log file with priority queue for increasing timestamp and get the parameter, he screwed me by asking what if the same user queries the same parameter would you go through the log file again ? I said I can cache it . I ran out of time for this one but neverth less can you guys give me a good design for this ?

Comment: This kind of system question is by design open ended.  Anything you say, can be made more complex with a follow-up question.  And any response will likewise be incomplete.  Because if you push it far enough, you needed to do something more sophisticated.  In real life, of course, you can throw it into a database or else logstash it.

Answer (score 0):

If I were interviewing you, and you had a design in mind that someone had given you from the internet, then the next question would be a change in the requirements to make that design no longer fit. The purpose of open design questions is usually to see how you, yourself approach design problems not whether there is a 'good' solution to them.

Comment: Hi Pete, Totally agree I'd just like to know how you would approach this problem